# Existence of direct summand isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}_p[P]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $P$ be a cyclic group of order $p^n$. Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}_p[P]$-module and $M_p :=\mathbb{Q}_p\otimes M$ be the associated $\mathbb{Q}_p[P]$-module. When will $M_p$ have a direct summand isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}_p[P]$?

We know $\mathbb{Q}[P]\simeq \bigoplus_{d\mid p^n}\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_d)$.
If $M_p\simeq \bigoplus_{d\mid p^n}M_{p,d}$ where $M_{p,d}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_d)\otimes \mathbb{Q}_p$ and $m_d$ is its dimension, then $M_p\simeq \bigoplus_d (\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_d)\otimes \mathbb{Q}_p)^{m_d}$ as $\mathbb{Q}_p[P]$-modules. When does $M_p$ have a free rank one direct summand?

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand the question. Is the answer not just: when $m_d\geq 1$ for all $d\mid p^n$? The ring $\mathbf{Q}_p[P]$ is the direct product of fields $\mathbf{Q}_p(\zeta_d)$, $d\mid p^n$.

Comment: Sure, but are there some (not very strict) conditions on say the $\dim_{\mathbb{Q}_p} M_p$ so that we know this will happen?

Comment: Imposing some condition on the dimension of $M_p$ as a $\mathbf{Q}_p$-vector space will not be enough to ensure that $M_p$ has a submodule (equivalently, direct summand) isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}_p[P]$. Take $M=\mathbf{Z}_p^n$ for any $n\geq 1$ with trivial $P$-action. Then $\dim_{\mathbf{Q}_p}(M_p)=\dim_{\mathbf{Q}_p}(\mathbf{Q}_p^n)=n$. Can you elaborate on what you might be looking for, or if there is something you specifically want to do with $M_p$?

Comment: $K$ be a number field and $F/K$ be a cyclic $p$-power Galois extension. $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $K$. $S(E/F)$ be the Selmer group and $M$ be its Pontryagin dual. Then Mazur-Rubin (2007) show that under some natural conditions, if $\dim M_p$ is odd then $m_d\geq 1$ for all $d$. If $R(E/F)$ is a subgroup of $S(E/F)$ (in particular, the fine Selmer group) and we define $M^\prime$ to be its Pontryagin dual etc. then can one draw conclusions as to when $M^\prime_p$ will have a direct summand isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}_p[P]$. Maybe using the semi-simplicity of $\mathbb{Q}_p[P]$?